# Flink : How to implement TypeInformation without actual number of columns in csv

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading a csv file through flink. csv file have a specific number of columns.

I have defined

```
            RowCsvInputFormat format = new RowCsvInputFormat(filePath, 
            new TypeInformation[]{  
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO
    });
```

The code works fine if in the file all the rows have proper 4 columns.

I want to handle a scenario when few rows in the file do not have 4 columns OR there is any other issue in few rows.

How can i achieve this in flink.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here at the specifications on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Standardization) or the [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) it seems like CSV files *should* only contain rows which have the same amount of columns. So it makes sense the RowCsvInputFormat would not support this.

You could read the files using [readTextFile(path)](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/batch/#data-sources) and then in a `flatMap()` operator parse the strings into a Row object (or ignore if there are issues in a row)

```
env.readTextFile(params.get("input"))
   .flatMap(someCsvRowParseFunction())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using:

```
format.setLenient(true);
```